# Traer los últimos 20 registros y sacar promedio, dependiendo de la fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Seré breve, necesito sacar los ultimos 20 registros, y una vez los obtenga sacar un promedio, eso dependiendo de la fecha en que estoy parado, hasta el momento tengo este query en sql server:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#V_ECP_ORG_COMPLETION_FORMA') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #V_ECP_ORG_COMPLETION_FORMA;


SELECT A.* INTO #V_ECP_ORG_COMPLETION_FORMA FROM [V_ECP_ORG_COMPLETION_FORMAS ] A
WHERE A.ORG_UNIT6_NAME = @Campo_Contrato
AND A.COMPLETION_NAME = @Completion;




;WITH BOLLIGER AS (
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY B.START_DATETIME ASC) AS CONTADOR,
        A.COMPLETION_NAME AS SARTA,
        B.START_DATETIME AS FECHA, 
        CAST(B.BSW_VOL_FRAC * 100 AS NUMERIC (11,3)) AS BSW,
        B.VALID_TEST AS [VALIDA PRUEBA], 
        B.OIL_VOL_RATE AS VOLUMEN
    FROM #V_ECP_ORG_COMPLETION_FORMA   A  INNER JOIN VT_WELL_TEST_RAW_es_CO B ON A.ITEM_ID = B.ITEM_ID 
    WHERE B.START_DATETIME >= (SELECT DATEADD(d,-365,GETDATE()))
    --order by B.START_DATETIME OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT (SELECT CAST(CEILING(COUNT(*) * .4) AS INT) FROM BOLLIGER) ROWS ONLY
)



    SELECT 
       A.CONTADOR,
      -- CASE WHEN A.CONTADOR = 21 THEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.FECHA ASC)) END AS CONTADOR2,
        A.SARTA, 
        A.FECHA, 
        A.BSW, 
        A.VOLUMEN
        --,CAST((
        --  SELECT AVG(B.BSW)
        --  FROM BOLLIGER B
        --  WHERE B.FECHA <  A.FECHA 
        --  --and B.CONTADOR <= 20
        --  --HAVING (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY B.FECHA ASC)) <= 20
        --) AS  NUMERIC (11,3)) PROMEDIO






    FROM BOLLIGER  A

    ORDER BY A.SARTA, A.FECHA ASC
```

lo que esta comentado pensé que me servía pero no, pues tiene en cuenta todos los promedios, mas no los últimos 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que quieres mostrar todos los registros y ademas en una columnas mostrar solo el promedio de los ultimos 20. En ese caso este código te podría servir(selecciono los ultimos de acuerdo a la columna FECHA):

```
SELECT 
A.CONTADOR,
A.SARTA, 
A.FECHA, 
A.BSW, 
A.VOLUMEN,
X.PROMEDIO
FROM BOLLIGER  A  CROSS JOIN
(SELECT AVG(BSW) PROMEDIO FROM (SELECT TOP(20)BSW FROM BOLLIGER ORDER BY FECHA DESC)B)X
ORDER BY A.SARTA, A.FECHA ASC
```

**ACTUALIZACION**

Una vez aclarado que el promedio debe ser por los ultimos 20 registros que hayan antes de cada fecha el codigo debe ser asi:

```
SELECT 
A.CONTADOR,
A.SARTA, 
A.FECHA, 
A.BSW, 
A.VOLUMEN,
(SELECT AVG(B.BSW) FROM (SELECT TOP(20)BSW FROM BOLLIGER X WHERE X.FECHA<A.FECHA ORDER BY X.FECHA DESC)B)PROMEDIO
FROM BOLLIGER  A  
ORDER BY A.SARTA, A.FECHA ASC
```

Comment: hola german, gracias por la respuesta, pero no es asi, de pronto fue que no me hice explicar bien, por cada fecha que me saque, me debe votar los ultimos 20 promedios, pero creo que en la manera como lo hiciste, lo puedo hacer es con una funcion escalar. de igual forma muchas gracia por la idea

Comment: @SadidLeonardo es decír debe ser promediado de acuerdo a la fecha? Por cada fecha debe aparecer el promedio de los últimos 20? Si es así ya te actualizo la solución

Comment: @SadidLeonardo o son las ultimas 20 antes del registro?

Comment: @SadidLeonardo revisa la actualizacion que subi y me comentas ocmo te va

Comment: muchas gracias, esa era la solucion, muchas gracias german

Comment: @SadidLeonardo me alegro, no olvides marcar la respuesta como la solucion.